# I can't seem to find the right Collection for my case. Thinking about list of hashmap of list, which appears very abstract

Tags: java, collections

I'm currently trying to write this programm challenge: https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/2hcwzn/09242014_challenge_181_intermediate_average_speed/

Basically, I've gotte to the point where the cars pass the 4 cameras, and I want to save the time every car has passed a specific camera individually.

So far my thought process was to do a list of a hashmap of lists, but I feel like I'm thinking too abstract, mostly because I am really not feeling too safe with which collection to use at which time (thats why I'm doing this exercise mostly).

Basically, my list would consist of various hashmaps of lists. The "lowest" lists would contain all 4 time dates for a specific car ( data for camera one, data for camera two, and so on). Then I would attach this list to a hashmap, which would have the specific plate of the car as key. The "highest" collection list would then include all the hashmaps, so basically the list would store all car plates which store all data for each camera.

I feel like I made it a little bit hard to follow, so I painted this mindmap for you: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jps7P.png

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: A `List<Map<String, List>>`? That sounds horrible to me. Use a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object).

Comment: I agree with @ElliottFrisch, just think how much time it will take to search million X million entries. For the implementation's sake,  you can work out a `Pub/Sub` model where each camera will publish as well as receive data from other cameras and cars data will be available globally. Again its just an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the speed limit, you just need a number... Maybe use a `double`?
For the cameras, you need an array or a List of distance (`int`s). Either adt is fine

To track if a car is speeding, you can use a `Map<String,Date>` to record their last position. Then, as you process each set of camera data, you can use this `Map` to get the last data, do your speeding calculations, and then put the new data into the `Map` so that when you're processing the next camera data, it will be up to date.

That's how I might design it... Make sense?

Comment: Thats a great solution, thanks. I just had this mind block which was making me think way too abstract.